# aws ec2 export-image task is stuck at 85% - StatusMessage: converting

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I see a weird problem where the export-image task is stuck at 85% or can say at the "conversion" step and it doesn't end even after 6 hours waiting.
Steps used are pretty normal :

```
% aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-0123c45d6789d012d --disk-image-format VMDK --s3-export-location S3Bucket=ami-snapshots-bucket --region us-west-2
```

And here is the status stuck at 85% :

```
% aws ec2 describe-export-image-tasks --export-image-task-ids export-ami-0ddfc0123456789d1 --region us-west-2
{
    "ExportImageTasks": [
        {
            "ExportImageTaskId": "export-ami-0ddfc0123456789d1",
            "Progress": "85",
            "S3ExportLocation": {
                "S3Bucket": "ami-snapshots-bucket"
            },
            "Status": "active",
            "StatusMessage": "converting",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone with similar issue or know to make this work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

For 80 GB storage, mine finished in about 2 hrs, though it was stuck at 85% for while.

Another internet user also suggests that [3 hrs until completion worked for them](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=326124) for a 40 GB image/snapshot.